# How to use SkiaSharp with MvvmCross and Xamarin.Forms for iOS?

Tags: ios, xamarin.forms, mvvmcross, skiasharp

Currently I am trying to create an application for drawing on iOS. This is going to be only a prototype. Later I will port an existing application (based on MvvmCross) to iOS.  Therefore I set up a Xamarin.Forms project and included the **MvvmCross 6.2.2** Framework according to the [TipCalcTutorial](https://www.mvvmcross.com/documentation/tutorials/tipcalc/a-xamarin-forms-version?scroll=1822). This works fine (I just build it for **iOS 12.1** with the iPhone Simulator in Visual Studio for Mac).

But I did not manage to include the SkiaSharp Framework Version 1.6. I added the SkiaSharp.Views.Forms Package from NuGet and integrated an SKCanvasView to my XAML (the app has just this one View).

But when I run my app it does not start and  I got the following exception:

**NSInternalInconsistencyException Reason: Application windows are expected to have a root view controller at the end of application launch**

If I comment out the SKCanvasView it works.
I did some research but I did not find a solution for it. 
I could imagine that SkiaSharp has problems with the altered iOS project structure (due to MvvmCross there is no ViewController anymore).

Here is my View with the SkiaSharp elements:

```
<views:MvxContentPage x:TypeArguments="viewModels:MainViewModel"
xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" 
xmlns:views="clrnamespace:MvvmCross.Forms.Views;assembly=MvvmCross.Forms"
xmlns:mvx="clr-namespace:MvvmCross.Forms.Bindings;assembly=MvvmCross.Forms"
xmlns:viewModels="clr-namespace:FormsPrototype.Core.ViewModels;assembly=FormsPrototype.Core"
xmlns:skia="clr-namespace:SkiaSharp.Views.Forms;assembly=SkiaSharp.Views.Forms"
x:Class="FormsPrototype.UI.Pages.MainView">

<ContentPage.Content> 
    <Grid x:Name="ContentGrid">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="1*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="3*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical" Grid.Row="0">
        <Label Text="Xamarin Drawing Prototype" /> 
        <Button Text="Start" Command="{Binding StartSimCmd}" />
   </StackLayout>

     <!-- Canvas-->
   <skia:SKCanvasView Grid.Row="1"  PaintSurface="OnPaintSurface">
   </skia:SKCanvasView> 

 </Grid>
</ContentPage.Content>
```

So it is possible to use the SkiaSharp Framework with Xamarin.Forms and MvvmCross? And how can I do that ?

Comment: what's the minimum version of iOS you are targeting? on which iOS are you testing?

Comment: is it possible to use SkiaSharp with MVVMCross?